# Video taken from front camera always rotates 270 angle after merging video

Tags: android, mp4parser

I'm merging two videos using `mp4parser` library `isoviewer-1.0-RC-27.jar`. One video is taken from back camera and other is taken from front camera.

It always rotates the video by 270 degree which is taken from front. I don't want any rotation in that. I have tried to give rotation by HeaderTrackBox, but rotation is implemented for entire video. Any how I'm not able to give individual rotation to each video while merging them.